# Connection refused [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379] redis on shared hosting

Tags: laravel-5, redis, shared-hosting

I am trying to deploy laravel 5 app on shared hosting and it uses redis for broadcasting. It displays error

> **Connection refused [tcp://{{hosting IP here}}:6379]**

I have also enabled redis option in hosting, I am using php 5.6.

Comment: Did you try connecting directly to Redis to verify that it is actually up and reachable? (use redis-cli or even just telnet)

Comment: @ItamarHaber Can you please guide me how can I use redis-cli in cpanel. I worked first time on redis.

Comment: Sorry - I'm not familiar with the cpanel integration that your hosting provider provides... if they give you shell access, just run it/telnet from there

Comment: No I don't have shell access, thanks for your response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, I had to make sure redis was installed and running.

To run Redis:
`redis-server`

Test that it's running:
`redis-cli ping` (returns `PONG`).

Now run Laravel Horizon:
`php artisan horizon`

Comment: and most of the shared hosting providers do not have redis installed by default